# "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" when running a simpleSSL client

Tags: java, ssl, rabbitmq

I am attempting to create a client/server using the SSL communication. I followed the instructions listed here  (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

I am greeted with this error:

while running the server :

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:134)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:277)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:678)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:722)
```

while using the client :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:134)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:277)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:678)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:722)
    at rmqClient.simpleSSL.main(simpleSSL.java:23)
```

here's my rabbit.config file :

```
[
    {ssl, [{versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']}]},
    {
    rabbit,
    [
          {ssl_listeners, [5675]},
      {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"sslConn/ca_certificate.pem"},
                          {certfile,  "sslConn/server_certificate.pem"},
                          {keyfile,   "sslConn/server_key.pem"},
                          {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']},
                          {ciphers,  [{ecdhe_ecdsa,aes_128_cbc,sha256},
                                      {ecdhe_ecdsa,aes_256_cbc,sha}]}
                         ]},     
          {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
          {loopback_users, []}
        ]
    }
].
```

here's also my client code :

```
    factory.setHost("10.3.9.139");
    factory.setPort(5673);
    factory.setUsername("User1");
    factory.setPassword("User1");
    factory.useSslProtocol();
    Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare("rabbitmq-java-test", false, true, true, null);
    channel.basicPublish("", "rabbitmq-java-test", null, "Hello, World".getBytes());
```

Answer (score 4):

`java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` is generally speaking caused by remote peer closed connection.

I guess your SSL config didn't fit well with server.
Suggestion here is to debug SSL connection to find root cause.

Try to append this system property to your JVM params:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: I am getting same error when trying to hit from soapui.. Can you please let me know that where do i need to add -Djavax.net.debug=all?

Comment: I have added in SoapUI-5.0.0.vmoptions.. Let me see i am able to resolve the issue. I did not get any clue.. getting same errorlog..

Comment: I wish I'd known about `-Djavax.net.debug=all` about 5 weeks ago! If you're using Tomcat, you'll need to find the right place in `catalina.sh` to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this in Java 1.7 by specifying:
  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

Answer (score 0):

In the v configuration you have set port 5675 for SSL listener, but in code you are using 5673.